# How to parse SOAP Response Containing Node Attributes in PHP

Tags: php, xml, soap

I am having a difficult time understanding how to view/use an XML result from a SOAP call in PHP.  I have a script which makes a SOAP request to a script on another server,  and it sends an XML response. That response has a number of nested nodes,  some of which have attributes.  I am able to make the SOAP call and get the response,  however,  using var_dump and print_r gives me the XML array without the attributes.

Here is the code breakdown:

**Code Snippet in PHPH script which makes the SOAP request**

```
use_soap_error_handler(true);
$client = new SoapClient(null, array("uri" => "Lic", "location" => "http://mydomain.com/Lic.cgi", "trace" => 1));
$assets = $client->Menu($email,$account_id);
```

**Expected Response**
The call generates the following (style of) XML result on the other server:

```
<opt>
    <Account>
        <Asset id="1000">
            <Menu type="simple">Software</Menu>
        </Asset>
        <Asset id="2000">
            <Menu type="modal">Software</Menu>
            <Menu type="simple">Demo</Menu>
        </Asset>
    </Account>
</opt>
```

Notice that Asset and Menu nodes have node attributes (id, type, etc).

**Actual Results**
When I do a var_dump or print_r on $assets,  I do get successful results,  but I cannot see the attributes (id,  type, etc) anywhere.   The ultimate goal is to take XML array and write the data to a MySQL table,  but I would need the attributes as well,  and days of searching has not yielded the missing piece on how I can access the full data results in PHP.

**VAR DUMP**
The var_dump would result in something like:

```
object(stdClass)#44 (1) {
  ["Account"]=>
  object(stdClass)#45 (1) {
    ["Asset"]=>
    array(2) {
      [0]=>
      object(stdClass)#46 (1) {
        ["Menu"]=>
        string(12) "Software"
      }
  ....
```

**PRINT_R**
And print_r($assets) gives something like:

```
stdClass Object
(
    [Account] => stdClass Object
    (
        [Asset] => Array
        (
        [0] => stdClass Object
        (
            [Menu] => Software
        )
        [1] => stdClass Object
        (
        [Menu] => Array
            (
            [0] => Software
                [1] => Demo
            )
            ...
```

Aside from var_dump and print_r,  is there another way to view the results,  in order to see the full data,  including the attributes?

Thanks in advance,  and I apologize if I'm not asking the question properly (if so, please let me know so that I can rephrase using the right terminology).

Comment: Can you provide the wsdl for the soap?

Comment: [**`SimpleXMLElement`**](http://www.php.net/manual/pt_BR/class.simplexmlelement.php) and [**`SimpleXMLElement::xpath`**](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/simplexmlelement.xpath.php) would help you in this journey.

Comment: I will find out.  (I am only working on the PHP side of things here. Another developer is working on an internal server, running that CGI script to generate the data).

Comment: There's no WSDL. It's a PERL script which uses something like ... "return SOAP::Data->type('xml' => $xml_content);"   ... where the $xml_content contains the "XML" data in post above.